# What character encoding does a request object for afterSave in Parse use?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, parse-platform

When I attempt to POST some data in an `afterSave()` hook on Parse, I notice some exceptions like: `Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20\\n at [Source: [B@7199e442; line: 1, column: 161]`

Looking at the the Data Browser for Parse, I see the appropriate character `å` but from the Parse logs, the POST'ed data looks like `Ã¥` which is either just a problem with the encoding in the logs or a clue that the string attributes of `request.object` in `Parse.Cloud.afterSave("myObject", function(request) {...}`have a non-UTF-8 encoding!

So my question becomes, what character encoding does a `request.object` for afterSave in Parse use?

I know of one other scenario where folks ran into some strange encoding issues but not exactly the same thing: https://www.parse.com/questions/text-encoding-problem-in-nested-dictionaries

Comment: On the actual Post thats input, are you specifying "content-encoding" . that specific encode value may play out thru the 'request.object' in your code??

Comment: Great point! I use saveAll() which is a Parse JS SDK method to batch saves, at which point I don't have control over providing "content-encoding" and afterSave() is a trigger downwind from that workflow. I could try to sniff the packets that parse client sends during saveAll to confirm but it still won't help me take control or fix anything ... hmm.

Comment: Hmm. maybe look at the minified parse.js. If you know what backbone does, i think parse just extend it. i dont even know what package the actual Http client is in..

Comment: any update on this subject? I have a similar problem: on an afterSave i send data to an external service which responds that the string is not proper utf8

Comment: @jrmgx - nope ... so i'm developing an approach to move away from parse.com seamlessly, drop my code elsewhere and flip a switch